# Facing issues in Bazel build when trying to Integrate one repository as a remote repo to another repository

Tags: gitlab, repository, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp

We have a repository which uses bazel build,
Folder structure is such that
remote_repo -> source -> BUILD
we have added target in BUILD file like //source:target (starts from root folder)
This works fine when we run Bazel command in remote_repo

Now this repository is added as a remote repo to another repository in git in the form of submodule.
Folder structure is like
actual_repo -> applications -> our_application -> remote_repo -> source -> BUILD
When I try to compile actual repo which has its own BUILD file and remote repo BUILD is added as dependent target, am getting error: as no package found at source (//source:target starts from root, it is not able to find target).

How to resolve such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that you now have to use a longer path like `//applications/our_application/remote_repo/source:target` as target labels are relative to the `WORKSPACE` root.

Another option would be to include the submodule as a `local_repository()` and referencing your target as `@remote_repo//source:target` (given you've named the repository accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

By making the relative path as //applications/our_application/remote_repo/source:target and building remote repo in own applicatio  i am getting below error: no such package '@remote_repo//application/own_application/remote_repo/src':
BUILD file not found in directory 'application/own_application/remote_repo/src' of external repository @remote_repo.
Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package. and referenced by '@remote_repo//:remote_repo'